# Not getting the expected answer from the code I wrote for probability assignment

Tags: python-3.x, data-analysis, probability

Here is the problem statement =>
In a game involving the toss of a fair coin, players gain $5 for heads and lose $3 for tails. After 8 tosses, calculate the probability of achieving a net gain of exactly $20.
I have to solve the question using Binomial distribution and also need to write the python code which verifies the answer.

So I decided to write the code.
Here is the code =>

```
import random

toss = [0,1]
#0 for head
#1 for tail
def run():
    gain = 0
    for i in range(8):
        if random.choice(toss) == 0:
            gain += 5
        else:
            gain -= 3
    return gain #final gain for 8 trials
    # print("this is final gain {}".format(gain))

#print(run())
num_of_tests = 0
while run() != 20:
    print(run())
    num_of_tests += 1
    print("Tests ran => ", num_of_tests)
```

Using this code I am not getting the final gain as $20 after 8 trials even I loop the 1000 times.
I am confused. Where  I did wrong.
Is there a bug in code.
Or the answer to the question is 0%?

Comment: You cant get exactly 20 in 8 tosses.

Comment: Your code ran 1_116_677 times on my REPL and had to interrupt it

Comment: Mr. Matthias, how you obtain exactly 20 in 8 tosses. Do you have the code that proves that?

Comment: Yes Journpy. That's what my question. do we get exactly 20 in 8 tosses?

Answer (score 0):

basic maths: gain = n_heads  * 5  - 3 * (N_tosses - n_heads)
So: gain = n_heads*8 - 3 * N_tosses

a gain of 20 with 8 tosses would mean :
20 = 8 * n_heads - 3*8

So n_heads = 44/8 thus n_heads = 11/2 which is not possible

no need for python code for that ...
If you REALLY want to write a code I would do it like that:

```
import random

def gain():
    return random.choice([-3,5])

def proba(x,results):
    return results.count(x) / len(results)

n_trials = 2000
n_tosses = 8
#for each trial, compute the sum of the gains for a given number of tosses
results = [sum([gain() for _ in range(n_tosses)]) for _ in range(n_trials)]
print(proba(20,results))
```

which will always give you 0 whatever the number of trials you put...